# TypeError: parse is not a function on csv-parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, node-csv-parse

I ran into this issue after setting up a simple app using:

- node v16.13.2
- npm v8.1.2
- csv-parse v5.0.4
  On
- VSCode v1.63.2

Code is:

```
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');

const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('kepler_data.csv')
    .pipe(parse({
        comment: "#",
        columns: true,
    }))
    .on('data', (data) => {
        results.push(data);
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log(results);
        console.log('Done!');
    });
```

Running it resulted in:

```
index.js:7
    .pipe(parse({
          ^

TypeError: parse is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jadeye/node.js_workspace/PLANETS-PROJECT/index.js:7:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
```

Searching [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) gave similar results but no actual solution.

Answer (score 32):

Solution was simple. If `parse` or any other function is not recognized with `node require`,
try getting the function itself as:

```
const { parse } = require('csv-parse');
```

Something worth noting it the color scheme that emphasizes the difference between the `const parse` color = **white**, and the usage of the function `parse` inside `pipe` = **green**.

[image: errornous call]

And the colors without error where `const { parse }` is **green**, matchin the `const` call.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. Try  `const {parse} = require('parse')` instead of  `const parse = require('parse')`
   OR
2. Try **csv-parse** version instead `"csv-parse": "^3.0.0"` of `"csv-parse": "^5.3.0"`

[csv-parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czn7B.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {parse} = require("csv-parse");

const results = [];

fs.createReadStream("./kepler_data.csv").pipe(parse({
   comment: '#',
   columns: true,
})).on('data', (data) => {
   results.push(data)
}).on('end', () => {
   console.log(results);
   console.log('done ');
})
```

This works for me

Answer (score 2):

```
const { parse } = require("csv-parse");
```

This works for me instead of this:

```
const parse = require('csv-parse');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try destructuring the actual functions from the import.
Instead of
`const parse = require('csv-parse');`
Use:
`const { parse } = require('csv-parse');`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

> const { parse } = require('csv-parse');

Try Following

> const { parse } = require("csv-parse");

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was changing from "csv-parse" to "csv-parser"

Use this in package.json

```
"csv-parser": "^3.0.0"
```

Instead of:

```
"csv-parse": "v5.0.4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring the parse function worked for me.

const {parse} = require("csv-parse");

Answer (score 0):

get the parse function it self in the csv-parse module by doing
const {parse} = require("csv-parse");

and call .pipe(parse())

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```js
const {parse} = require('csv-parse');
```

instead of :

```js
const parse = require('csv-parse');
```